# Is $a_{2n} < a_n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion, divergent-series

Suppose we have 2 convergent series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ and  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{2n}$. Does that mean that $a_{2n} \leq a_n$?

Comment: Take $a_n=0$, but I don't get the point of your question.

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{2n}\le\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$?

Comment: No, it doesn't.    Eventually $a_n \to 0$ and $a_{2n} \to 0$ so in general an $a_k$ for a large $k$ will in general be smaller than an $a_m$ for a small $m$ but there can be many, many, exceptions.   Consider $a_n = n$ for all $n\le 10^{100}$ but $a_{n} = \frac 12a_{n-1}$ for $n > 10^{100}$.  Then $a_{2000} = 2000 > 1000 = a_{1000}$.

Comment: Separate from the analysis in fleablood's comment above, what about the counter example -(1) + (1/2) -(1/4) +(1/8) ...  It's immediate that the overall summation is convergent to a negative number, and the summation of the even terms is convergent to a positive number.  Thus, if you try to repair your hypothesis re the analysis of fleablood and others, you must also accommodate my counter-example.

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider $a_n = 1$ if $n=2$, and $a_n =0$ for all $n \neq 2$. Then your two series converge, but $a_2 > a_1$.

Comment: Thanks! I got it!

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not.  Try
$$ a_n = \cases{1/2^n & if $n$ is even\cr 0 & if $n$ is odd\cr} $$

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense.